# Alert flash message not working with respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, respond-with

I'm using [responders](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) gem in my Rails 4.2 application. I got a pretty complex situation, where in a `Organization` model edit view I got a  form for a `OrganizationUser` with one input. Adding user to organization invokes a `create` action in a `OrganizationUsersController`. I am using responders there with redirect action, something like this:

```
def create
  @organization_user = @organization.organization_users.create(organization_user_params)
  respond_with @organization_user do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to edit_organization_path(@organization) }
  end
end
```

And my translations:

```
flash:
  actions:
    create:
      notice: '%{resource_name} was successfully created.'
      alert: '%{resource_name} could not be created.'
  organization_users:
    create:
      notice: "Member has been added"
      alert: "Validation error"
```

The problem is that everything works if a resource is valid and is persisted to database. I am redirected to edit organization view with a proper notice message, but if validation fails I am redirected without any alert.

I can of course set flash alert message unless `@organization_user` is persisted, but that's the whole point of using responders to set flashes automatically.

Comment: Need full method controller

Comment: Edited. Nothing special

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. It turned out that with validation errors flash was properly set, but it was `flash.now` instead of `flash` and after `redirect_to` flash was deleted. The solution is to use `:flash_now => false` like so:

```
respond_with(@organization_user, :flash_now => false) do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to edit_organization_path(@organization) }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
respond_with @organization_user do |format|
  if @organization_user.valid?
    format.html { redirect_to edit_organization_path(@organization) }
  end
end
```

Comment: But I always want to be redirected to edit_organization_path, even if validation fails.

Comment: as this can work just a bit more on what is happening add how to get to this Answer will help

Answer (score 1):

Note that for flashes in your `config/locales/en.yml` to work, you need `responders :flash` at the top of your controller.